# Disable or enable fields according to selected value

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an assessment excel file, and I have a column with a predefined values. If chose yes in this field, I want to disable columns C, D and E, and fill F and G.

And if I set the value to No, I need to disable F and G and fill C, D and E.

Any ideas ?

I tried this:

> 1) Color a cell based on the value in another cell on the same row.
>
> If you need to color column A based on the values in column B:
>
> a) highlight column A b) go to Home > Conditional Formatting > New
>   Rule > Use a formula > Edit the Rule Description c) Formula is:
>   =B1="yes" Format...Fill: Green OK > OK

from [this link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/833601-enable-and-disable-a-cell-based-on-a-combination.html) but I cannot apply it to all `B` cells and I don't know how to lock it.

Comment: You can lock, unlock columns based on condition then protect sheet.

Comment: check the edit please.